# PyDev and Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am running Eclipse 4.2, PyDev worked fine with it until recently it stopped working (there is no longer a PyDev View), if I try to update pydev, I get this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software currently installed: Eclipse SDK 4.2.0.I20120608-1400 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 4.2.0.I20120608-1400)
  Missing requirement for filter properties ~= $0: Eclipse Product Configuration 1.0.0.I20120608-1400 (org.eclipse.rcp.configuration.feature.group 1.0.0.I20120608-1400) requires 'org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.gtk.linux.x86 [1.0.0.I20120608-1400]' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse SDK 4.2.0.I20120608-1400 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 4.2.0.I20120608-1400)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.configuration.feature.group [1.0.0.I20120608-1400]
```

I just realised it says: `org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.gtk.linux.x86`. I recently upgraded my system from 32bit to 64bit, might that be the reason and if it is the reason how can I fix it?

Comment: Already did that, didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `~/.eclipse` and reinstalling all plugins solved the problem.